# How to remove elements of column which are similar in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns, `groups_added` and `groups_removed`.
How can I remove elements from `group_added` if they are present in `group_removed` and remove the elements of `group_removed` simultaneously?

Eg:

```
id      group_added    group_removed
4       "G4,G3"        "G4"
11      "G4,G3"        "G3"
15      "G2,G3"        "G2"
16      "G3"           "G1"
26      "G2"           "G3"
46      "G3"           "G4"
50      "G4,G2"        "G4"
```

I expect it to return something like:

```
id      group_added    group_removed
4       "G3"           ""
11      "G4"           ""
15      "G3"           ""
16      "G3"           "G1"
26      "G2"           "G3"
46      "G3"           "G4"
50      "G2"           ""
```

Comment: What is `type(df['group_added'].values[0])`?

Comment: It's of type str

Comment: Can you have more than two group values in `group_added`? And more than one in `group_removed`?

Comment: yes, There can be any number of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First step**: convert strings to lists.

```
df['group_added'] = df['group_added'].str.split(',')
df['group_removed'] = df['group_removed'].str.split(',')
```

Result:

```
   id group_added group_removed
0   4    [G4, G3]          [G4]
1  11    [G4, G3]          [G3]
2  15    [G2, G3]          [G2]
3  16        [G3]          [G1]
4  26        [G2]          [G3]
5  46        [G3]          [G4]
6  50    [G4, G2]          [G4]
```

**Second step**: apply the desired transformation.

```
result = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({
    'group_added': [g for g in row['group_added'] if g not in row['group_removed']],
    'group_removed': [g for g in row['group_removed'] if g not in row['group_added']]
}), axis=1)
```

**Third step**: convert lists back to strings.

```
result['group_added'] = result['group_added'].apply(','.join)
result['group_removed'] = result['group_removed'].apply(','.join)
```

Result:

```
  group_added group_removed
0          G3              
1          G4              
2          G3              
3          G3            G1
4          G2            G3
5          G3            G4
6          G2
```

Comment: How am I supposed to map id now?

Comment: `df[['group_added', 'group_removed']] = result`

Answer (score 0):

```
df["backup_group_added"] = df["group_added"]

def get_column_difference(row, left_column, right_column):
    difference = (list(set(row[left_column].split(",")) - set(row[right_column].split(","))))
    return ','.join(map(str, difference)) 

df['group_added'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_column_difference(row, 'group_added', 'group_removed'), axis= 1)

df['group_removed'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_column_difference(row, 'group_removed', 'backup_group_added'), axis= 1)

df.drop('backup_group_added', axis=1, inplace=True)
```